# Azure Data Lake Store data upload using az dls fs upload command

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

From a particular shell script i'm trying to upload a set of folders.
The folder structure is as below:
    parentfolder/folder1
    parentfolder/folder2

So from the parentfolder i'm doing a

```
 for directory in `find . -type d`
```

and finding the list of folders and doing a

```
az dls fs upload --account $adls_account --source-path $new_src_dir --destination-path $dest_dir$file_name --overwrite --thread-count $thread_count --debug
```

However, i'm facing one issue while the upload is happening. After the first upload is complete, it throws error saying:

```
Please run 'az account set' to select active account.
Failure in uploading file to Data Lake Store
```

can some please help me find the actual error. I've done the az_login and then started the for loop.

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try run this command `az account set --subscription <name or id>`, then run your script.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked. I found the issue too. I was doing a az_logout after looping through each directory. Now I've moved the az_logout after the complete iteration. My bad.. missed this point. :(